# Why is the date in the request body different from the date in the response body in postman

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, date, postman

I'm trying to post the date in the request body in postman

date_borrow: 2021-01-01 date_return: 2021-02-01

but the body response produces output

```
{
"success": true,
"message": "success",
"data": [
    {
        "date_borrow": "2020-12-31T16:00:00.000Z",
        "date_return": "2021-01-31T16:00:00.000Z"
    }
]
```

}

i use node.js express for rest-api

```
addBorrowingMember(req,res){
  let dataBorrowingMember = {
      date_borrow : req.body.date_borrow,
      date_return : req.body.date_return
  }

  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
      if (err) throw err;
      connection.query(
          `
          INSERT INTO borrowing SET ?;
          `
          , [dataBorrowingMember],
      function (error, results) {
          if(error) throw error;
          res.send({
              success: true,
              message: 'success',
          });
      });
      connection.release();
  })
```

},

I want the date format the same as the request body like this date_borrow: 2021-01-01 date_return: 2021-02-01

Comment: where are you sending the date back ? i can see only the success part in res.send

Comment: i send date to mysql database type date, but when get data in postman the date result doesn't match the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you use postgresql as database and postgresql stores date in UTC +00.

To choose a timezone:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_timezone_names;
```

And set as below given example:

```
ALTER DATABASE postgres SET timezone TO 'Europe/Berlin';
```

Use your DB name in place of postgres in above statement.

Comment: I use mysql database

Comment: I tried it on the mysql database, the result was an error

Comment: Sorry I never used mysql before

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not specify a timezone for express server, so the system defaulted the datetime to UTC … so there is a difference between the time you add ( even from the browser ) to the date saved by the server , it depends on the difference between your timeZone and the server UTC timeZone .

Comment: the browser will deal with it automatically. let it like it is and test it in the browser.

Comment: in browser still produce the same response body date